# How to hide a "Broken" file from Synaptic

Tags: package-management, synaptic

Am trying to install and use the two or three folding@home files in order to continue folding after a hard disk reinstall of the OS.

i can download the files and use rpm -i --nodeps folding@home.file and when i go to Synaptic and hit Reload, it complains that the file is "Broken".

When i had this problem the first time - a couple of years ago and on the now defunct hard disk, i kinda remember that there was a command line that i could use to "hide" or make Synaptic not consider that file as broken but can't find the command.  i thought it might be the flag --justdb but if i install the file with this flag, Synaptic still complains.

Have a great morning and please stay safe!  :)

Comment: `rpm` sounds like RedHat or derivates of it, Ubuntu does not use rpm-packages. Are you running Ubuntu at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

apt-get has the "hide" option.

Comment: I searched for this `hide` option in the results of `man apt-get` in Ubuntu 22.04, but I didn't find it. Please copy/paste the paragraph of the "hide" option of apt-get into your answer.